# Convert NSString to int HEX

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I'm trying to convert a `NSString` into int HEX array.

For instance if I have `@"HELLO"` and I would like to get `0x48 0x45 0x4c 0x4c 0x4f`

I have tried for each char of the string:

```
unsigned int hexInt;
sscanf([stringParam UTF8String], "%u", &hexInt);
```

and

```
unsigned int hexInt;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:stringParam]scanHexInt:&hexInt];
```

None of them seem to work.

What is the best way to get: `unsigned int res[]` from an ASCII `NSString`?

Comment: You could use : `dataUsingEncoding`.

Comment: Have you tried `res[i] = (int)[stringParam characterAtIndex:i];` in a loop?  (You do, of course, need to allocate the array first.)

Comment: The NSData object created would be printed like: <48656c6c 6f>, that's not really an hex array, and it's just ugly.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri - What NSData object?

Comment: If you convert NSString to array of integers you will always get decimal numbers, because that's the way they are store. If you want to display it as hex value do NSLog(@"0x%x", hexInt);

Comment: Truly they are stored in binary, printed in decimal with %d and in hex with %x.

Comment: @xxcv - If I could downvote your comment I would.  Integers are stored as bit strings.  The bits can be interpreted as binary, octal, decimal, hex, duodecimal -- whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to store the characters of a string in an array of integers, right?

If you're OK with using `unsigned short` (16 bits) instead of `unsigned int` (32 bits), that's really easy.

```
NSUInteger length = [stringParam length];
unichar *characters = malloc(sizeof(unichar) * length);
[stringParam getCharacters:characters range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];
// Do whatever you want with the characters, then, once you're done...
free(characters);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but I suspect that the original question is confused on the distinction between "hex" and "binary".  All data internal to modern computers is manipulated in "bits" -- ones and zeros.  An "integer" is generally 32 or 64 ones/zeros taken together.  A "character" is 8, 16, or 32 ones/zeros, depending on the specific character set and context.

To allow humans to examine these electronic ones and zeros, they must be presented in some human-readable form.  Simplest is "binary" -- eg, 00001010 binary has a numerical value of 10 (decimal).  Since binary is not very compact, "octal" was invented.  In octal the 00001010 binary value would be 012.

But most computer "words" are some multiple of 8 bits, and octal does not evenly represent multiples of 8 bits, so "hex" ("hexadecimal") was invented.  In hex, 00001010 is represented as 0A.

What this means is that the only time you "convert" something to hex is to display it.  But fairly frequently newbies get confused on this point and think that converting, say, a character to a numerical internal representation is "converting it to hex".

In fact, characters already *have* a numerical internal representation -- it's simply a matter of extracting the individual character and (optionally) "casting" it to an integer type (and note that "casting" does not change the value, just the type of variable it can be stored in).

In his last sentence, the OP indicated he wanted an array of `int` values.  The individual NSString characters already are integers, only of the `unichar` type.  "Converting" to integer is merely a matter of casting to the desired target type.

Comment: I mean representation, yes, it's still an int

Comment: Technically correct but not really an answer to my question, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try with this function:

```
- (NSArray *)stringToHex:(NSString *)str
{
    NSUInteger len = [str length];
    unichar *chars = malloc(len * sizeof(unichar));
    [str getCharacters:chars];

    NSMutableArray *hexArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]];
        [hexArray addObject:hexString];
    }
    free(chars);

    return hexArray;
}
```